# Show that is a probability space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $ \Omega:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:0<x,y \leq 1 \}$, let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of sets of $\Omega$ such that $$ \mathcal{F}:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:x \in A,0<y \leq 1 \}$$ where $A \in \mathscr{B}_{(0,1]} (Borel, \sigma-algebra)$. And let $P(\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:x \in A,0<y \leq 1 \})=\lambda(A)$ where lambda is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

-Show that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space.

I know what i have to do. First a have to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-algebra$ I have a problem to prove that:

If $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$, i have the following:

Let $A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $A:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:x \in A_1,0<y \leq 1 \}$ for some $A_1 \in \mathscr{B}_{(0,1]}$.

So $A^c$ must be $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}:x \in A_1^c,y \leq 0 \}$,  since $A_1 \in \mathscr{B}_{(0,1]}$ then $A_1^c \in \mathscr{B}_{(0,1]}$ but $y \leq 0$ so $A^c \notin \mathcal{F}$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ wouldnt be a probability space. (?)

Comment: That's not what $A^c$ is.  Try drawing a picture.

Comment: You want $\mathcal{F} = \{ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in A, 0 < y \le 1 \} : A \in \mathcal{B}_{ (0,1]) } \}$. So $\mathcal{F}$ is indeed a collection of sets.

Comment: I tried with a picture, but i cant see it yet.

Answer (score 0):

$\Omega = (0,1] \times (0,1]$, $\Omega \setminus \{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2 \mid x \in A,0 < y \leq 1\} = \{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \mid x \in A^c, 0< y \leq 1 \}$

You are somewhat right in thinking about $y \leq 0 $ since $$(A \times B)^c = (A \times B^c) \cup (A^c \times B) \cup (A^c \times B^c) $$

[image]

but you have to remember that you are taking complement with respect to a given set $\Omega$ and not the entire $\Bbb{R}^2$.

In logical terms, if you consider the negation of ($P$ and $Q$) this is  (not $P $ and $Q$) plus ($P$ and  not $Q$) plus  (not $P$ and not $Q$):

$$\sim(P \wedge Q) = (\sim P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge \sim Q) \vee (\sim P \wedge \sim Q)$$

In our case $Q$ is the condition $y \in (0,1]$ and $\sim Q = \{y \leq 0\} \cup \{y >1\}$ But since to be in $\Omega$ the condition $y \in (0,1]$ must be true we conclude that $\sim Q = \emptyset$.

See the drawing [image]

Comment: But, in this problem $\Omega=(0,\infty) \times (-\infty,1]$

Comment: In the drawings I consider $\Omega = \Bbb{R}$ In the problem $\Omega = (0,1]^2$